# pthread_mutex_t in bionic libc

Tags: android, android-ndk, mutex, ndk-build, bionic

I am trying to port a code that uses `glibc` into Android NDK and running into some issues related to `mutexes`. Currently our code uses `mutex.__data.__count` to cycle through all the locks, and release them one by one, we are also using it to check whether there's a lock on that mutex, but unfortunately `bionic libc`'s `pthread_mutex_t` struct has only one member `value` Anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You should not rely on implementation internals. If you need something that `pthread_mutex_t` does not provide, the only way for you is to implement your own mutex.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Those are implementation details that are subject to change (that's generally implied by `__name`), and they changed.